# Export ics file to google, apple and outlook calendar in php

Tags: php, calendar, outlook, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I want to export the *.ics file to Google, Apple and Outlook calendar.
I am using following urls to export the file but its giving me issue for some urls. Following are the details.

For Google export *.ics I am using url.
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/rossmontessori.org_2gbp51hggdr1j6rstfho88iqls%40group.calendar.google.com/private-407f2123de0296b5c886167f48d9a4a7/basic.ics

For Apple and Outlook
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/rossmontessori.org_2gbp51hggdr1j6rstfho88iqls%40group.calendar.google.com/private-407f2123de0296b5c886167f48d9a4a7/basic.ics

Its working fine for Apple and Outlook but giving error message for google calendar.

Error message:

**Cannot add calendar "Hot Lunch"**
You do not have access to Hot Lunch's calendar

Any one please help me for this one?

Thanks

Comment: You wrote "I am using following code", but where is a code?

Comment: I mean I am using that url's sorry for the wrong word.